# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::sortByDesc()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get a list of 5 recent projects and sort them in descending order based on the created_at date field.  I'm using Model::with() to avoid the n+1 problem.  Below is the code:

```
  $recentProjects = Project::with('visits','team')
                                ->whereYear('created_at',now()->year)
                                ->sortByDesc('created_at')->take(5)
                                ->get();
```

However, I get the error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::sortByDesc()

I tried different ways, like `Project::orderBy()` followed by with, and didn't workout either.

Comment: It should be `Project::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')`

Comment: Or `latest('created_at')->take(5)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `sortByDesc` method sorts the collection by field that belongs to some eloquent relation in your model.

If you are trying to sort collection with `sortByDesc` for **model** itself ( your current object of model), use `orderBy` rather than `sortByDesc` :

```
Project::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->with('visits','team')
    ->whereYear('created_at', now()->year)
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```